# Compare same function with different writing structure

Tags: python

I have a function defined as follows -- and I wasn't sure about the structure.

The **data** is the list of value that I pass, with a maximum count of 5-6.

The **prevValues** is the huge list that comes from the database.

Case 1 :

```
for k in data:
    for m in prevValues:
       if k['name'] == m:
           return (True)
```

Case 2 :

```
for m in prevValues:
    for k in data:
        if k['name'] == m:
           return (True)
```

What changes can I expect? Performance is not the goal, I'm still learning to write better code.

Comment: You should not use nested loops at all, but check `if k['name'] in prevValues`

Comment: Assuming the values involved are hashable, you are looking to see if `set(prevValues) & set(k['name'] for k in data)` is empty or not.

Comment: @chepner That wouldn't short-circuit. Might be significantly worse depending on the data.

Comment: @wim Does it matter?

Comment: From the two cases you've provided, there is no real difference, other than a match may be encountered sooner in one versus the other, based on ordering. Algorithmically speaking they have the same upper bound for execution time, and as others have noted the algorithm can be improved.

Comment: the change you can expect is execution time, let said that looping over the big list take 1s now let also assume the worse case scenery that the match is at the end, then case 1 would take 5s+ because you need to iterate over the big list 5 times, while case 2 would take only 1s because you iterate over it only one time